# FXM on CD servers

Tags: fxm

I'm looking for some documentation, articles about the `FXM` configuration on a distributed farm (**one CM and two CD**). I can see that the embed script is generating with the default settings for CM (CM address). I assume that I should reconfigure it so that the data for FXM is collected by the CD, which is available on the external network.

Can someone share some documentation or articles on this topic?

The `Sitecore` version is `9.1`.

Comment: When configuring FXM in a distributed environment, FXM supports the role-based configuration model. For information about the role-based configuration model, see the documentation - https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/91/platform-administration-and-architecture/rule-based-configuration.html

Answer (score 1):

FXM already contains OOTB configuration for Standalone/CM/CD,
you should not forget to switch your instance to a CD role and that's it.

By default FXM generates CM becaon script:

```
<script src="//cm-instance/bundle/beacon"></script>
```

You can try to replace cm instance to CD one when inserting script to your external site:

```
<script src="//cd-instance/bundle/beacon"></script>
```